# Ldap "&(uniquemember=cn=customer,cn=Groups,dc=uk,dc=mysitexxx,dc=com)(objectclass=groupofuniquenames))" , what does the filter mean?

Tags: ldap

I am looking into an OVD performance issue, where OVD brings back all the records from the backend OID. Have been through the thread dumps and heap dumps and understand what is happening. Yet to figure out why, it appears like something to do with a ceratin configuartion. I am a java developer new to ldap, so could you help me to understand what the the following filter means please. Especially uniquemember=cn=customer, part.

-b "cn=Groups,dc=uk,dc=xxx,dc=com" -s sub "(&(uniquemember=cn=customer,cn=Groups,dc=uk,dc=mysitexxx,dc=com)(objectclass=groupofuniquenames))" cn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [filter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#section-2) expression consists of 2 conjunctive (&) equality (=) conditions: `uniqueMember=some_dn` and `objectClass=some_class`.  Only entries that match the expression are included in the result set.
Entries must be in the search space, which is defined to be a subtree (scope -s) with a certain root node (search base -b ).

Comment: Thank you. Is the query asking for the CN of all the groups customer is a uniquemember?

Comment: That's right - cn is the only attribute returned by the query example.